# What happens if 7 Soldiers block a Phyrexian Obliterator?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This is a situation I am confronted with more often than I want to. My opponent attacks me with his [Phyrexian Obliterator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214386) (5/5). The card says:

*Trample;
Whenever a source deals damage to Phyrexian Obliterator, that source's controller sacrifices that many permanents.*

I have a lot of small creature tokens available to block with, lets take 7 Soldier tokens to make it simple. They are all 1/1. My opponent has 4 [Mutagenic Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233070) in his deck and I have reason to believe that he has one of those in his hands.

The situation forces me to block, otherwise I would die. Lets assume I only have 1 life left.

I decide to declare all 7 Soldier tokens as blockers, so that I survive even if he uses a Mutagenic Growth. The question is what happens if he does not boost it and I am blocking the 5/5 creature with 7 Soldiers.

If I would block with a single 7/x creature, I would deal 7 damage and I would be forced to sacrifice 7 permanents afterwards. But what about the 7 individual creatures? Do they still deal 7 damage or do they deal only deal 5? I am afraid the answer is 7, because they all deal damage at the same time, but I am not confident about my interpretation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Phyrexian Obliterator takes 7 damage.**

Besides first strike and double strike (which create a separate combat damage phase for first-strike damage), all creatures exchange combat damage simultaneously. So the Phyrexian Obliterator takes all 7 points of damage even though it only has 5 toughness.

To add insult to injury, its triggers go on the stack **after** state-based actions are checked (meaning it and 5 Soldiers are dead), so you'll have to sacrifice 7 permanents in addition to the 5 tokens you lost blocking it.